# Does an MKV tag/metadata editor for Mac OSX exist?

Tags: macos, metadata, matroska

I'm looking for an MKV meta tag editor. I'm using PLEX Media Server and PLEX Media Center on my iMac to see movies.

PLEX is great because it automatically finds and names my entire movie library with year, director, gender, original title, description, movie poster art, etc.

Unfortunately, it saves all the data only into an app DB file without editing any tags in the MKV files.

20% of the movies need to be fixed or PLEX needs help finding the correct movie name, so if I need to move all my library elsewere, I need to do all the tagging work again.

So, does an MKV meta tag editor exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. But it is possible. You need to write the tags as an xml file using [matroska's docs](https://www.matroska.org/technical/tagging-video-example.html). Then you need to merge it with the mkv file using the [MKVToolnix](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MKVtoolnix) tool set. The tool you want is mkvmerge GUI, use the attachments tab to add your xml file.

Comment: I usually use it to merge split movies, I'll take a look, thanky very much! I hope will be developed a more useful method in the future!

Answer (score 2):

The best tool you can get for this task is `mmg` as part of the `mkvtoolnix` package:

http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/

It contains a header-editor where you can change the 'tags'. It is available cross-platform, the link you are most interested in should be http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html#macosx.